# What causes int8_t and int_fast8_t to be different?

Tags: c++

I did some searching and understood the difference between these data types. However, what confuses me is that, what causes the difference. When I go to `stdin.h` library, I see that `int8_t` and `int_fast8_t` is typedef as `signed char`. So, it is the same, right? But then, why `int_fast8_t` is always faster or equal to `int8_t` in term of speed?

Comment: well, there are hundreds of `stdint.h` out there, I guess some of them define those two differently.

Comment: Reopened; this question is **not** about what the differences are between these types but **where** those differences come from.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes. I do understand the differences between them. What I am trying to find out is what is the thing that causes these differences, in which process? And How?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, with those definitions, for whatever platform you're on, `int8_t` and `int_fast8_t` are equally fast. On some platforms a size larger than 8 bits could be faster, and in that case it would be appropriate to typedef `int_fast8_t` to that larger type. And on platforms that don't have an 8-bit type (some DSPs define `char` as 16 or 32 bits, and some old systems used 9-bit bytes), `int8_t` won't exist, but `int_fast8_t` will.

Answer (score 0):

The `fast` version of `intN`s is guaranteed to be at least `N` bits size but rather being something which processor can handle natively.

On x86 it doesn't probably matter that match but for example old Alpha processors didn't support 8-bit or 16-bit types directly (at least the older versions). So this `int_fast8_t` was defined as 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

> So, it is the same, right?

Yes, on this particular implementation, it is. But in general, this need not be the case.

> But then, why `int_fast8_t` is always faster or equal to `int8_t` in term of speed?

If both types are the same, the equal part applies. If the implementation has something faster it can use, the types will not be the same and the `int_fast8_t` will perform better (in some sense). (The types may also differ, but yield the same performance, but that is still covered by the *"faster or equal"* part of the quote.)

Bottom of the line, there does not actually have to be a difference between `int8_t` and `int_fast8_t`, and it is not uncommon for them to be the same type.